# What is causing so many failures when I try to port my Chrome extension from chrome.identity.getAuthToken to launchWebAuthFlow?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, oauth-2.0

I want my extension to work in Firefox and the new chromium-Edge.
They don't work with `chrome.identity.getAuthToken`.
So I'm porting to `chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow`.
Background.js code follows:

````
```
const AUTH_URL = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=971865119963-n9f0c5n0hga44jpds61ea4btfq608pfh.apps.googleusercontent.com&response_type=token&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flnfajhkleofjochkapfbagfddgmpgble.chromiumapp.org&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fcalendar%20https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fphotoslibrary%20https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fphotoslibrary.sharing";

background.getAccessToken = function() {
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow({interactive: true, url: AUTH_URL}, function (response) {
    if (response) resolve(response);
    else {
        console.log(chrome.runtime.lastError.message);
        reject();
        }
    });
});
````

}

````
```
````

I've run this code in both the `background.js` and the popup `browser_action.js`.
It always returns an `undefined` response, 
and issues a failure message:

```
    Unchecked runtime.lastError: Authorization page could not be loaded.
```

or

```
    Error: redirect_uri_mismatch
```

The fact that in Chrome, using chrome.identity.getAuthToken, this has worked
fine for a couple years sorta proves my developer console oauth configuration is ok.

For five days now, I've followed every possible lead in stackOverflow,
and gotten nowhere. Please help!